# Asp Net Core Identity get user id on login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

on my login page of in Areas/Identity/Account/Login

I have this handler, I want to log which user is accessing the database by getting his Id. The problem is the claims are still empty even after the signing result is successful. Am I missing something? I know i can just find the user Id in database using the username  but that's just an extra database call i'd like to avoid if possible.

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
        {
            returnUrl ??= Url.Content("~/Account/Index");

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                _toast.AddErrorToastMessage("Dados inválidos.");
                return Page();
            }
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.UserName, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            var user = await _signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _context.Accesses.Add(new Access
                {
                    Description = "Login",
                    Machine = Environment.MachineName,
                    UserId = User.GetUserId(),
                    IpAddress = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.ToString()                    
                });

                try
                {
                    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
                }
                catch(DbUpdateException ex)
                {
                    _logger.LogInformation(ex.InnerException.ToString());
                }

                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }

            _toast.AddErrorToastMessage("Username / Password Incorrecto(s).");
            return Page();
            // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form           
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
 _signInManager.UserManager.GetUserAsync(User);
```

try using

```
_signInManager.UserManager.FindByNameAsync(Input.UserName)
```